# Small issue tracker like github issues in php

Tags: php, open-source, issue-tracking

For my next project I want to have small issue tracker like this on github (in php and mysql/sqlite), do I need to write it from scratch or is there something like this already (open source)?

Answer (score 1):

There is [MantisBT](http://www.mantisbt.org/) which uses PHP and MySQL but it's not exactly small.

Which functionality do you need?

Comment: Just the list of closed/open issues with editor and comments (I will use twitter for login). It would be nice if you can create your own templates so they look as you want.

Comment: Well MantisBT is open source so you can do what you want with the template but it's kind of big, maybe not what you want.

Comment: Yea, I think I will need to create my own.

Answer (score 1):

If you want work without code you can try one of these:

http://vermis.hellworx.com/ (Open source)

http://www.mantisbt.org/